# Unmarshalling XML - "is parameter must not be null"

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

```
library = (Library) u.unmarshal(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/programista15k/webapp/lore.xml"));
```

I'm getting:

> Message=is parameter must not be null
>   FATAL:   is parameter must not be null

Sounds pretty obvious - the XML file's lacking. But I'm as sure as I can be that I placed it correctly. It's in the package `com.programista15k.webapp`, it's named "lore.xml". In my previous project it worked fine, now I'm using Maven but I don't know why it should change anything.

If you need some more information I will gladly provide it, but I think I described my problem quite well. What's more is there to check for me?

Comment: This line is in the .java file in com.programista.webapp.view.

Comment: Did you put it in src/main/resources ? Please double-check the file is actually in the JAR.

Comment: The file was in "NetBeansProjects\MiddleEarth4\WebApp\src\main\java\com\programista15k\webapp". I put it in "src/main/resources" now, but nothing's changed. Should I modify my code as well?

" Please double-check the file is actually in the JAR" I'm sorry, I don't understand. I don't see any JAR file being generated (no "dist" folder in Maven project in NetBeans).

Comment: It should be at: NetBeansProjects\MiddleEarth4\WebApp\src\main\resources\com\prog‌​ramista15k\webapp

Comment: mvn clean install will generate a JAR for jar Maven projects. Have a look at it with a ZIP tool and check if the file is at the location you expect.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation's helped me solve the problem :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Maven, non-compiled resources should be located at src/main/resources by default.

So in your case you have to put them in:

```
NetBeansProjects\MiddleEarth4\WebApp\src\main\resources\com\‌​prog‌​ramista15k\web‌​app
```

If you have issues like these, you can double-check the JAR by looking at it with a ZIP tool and check if the resources are where you expect them to be.